# Python C Extension - Access to PyInterpreterState Internal Data Structure

Tags: c, python-3.x, cpython, python-extensions

I recently found that I could get the Python interpreter state by `PyInterpreterState_Get()` C-API. However, when I tried to access its members defined by `struct _is` in the extension code, during the setup stage, the compiler threw "incomplete definition of type 'struct _is'" error. I noticed that this data structure is defined in an internal header file `internal/pycore_interp.h`, which cannot be included in a C extension module. I wonder if there is any workaround for accessing `PyInterpreterState` structure in C extensions?

My code looks like this

```c
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>
// #include <pycore_interp.h> // Wouldn't work: file not found
// #include <internal/pycore_interp.h> // Wouldn't work: this header requires Py_BUILD_CORE define

static PyObject *
mymodule_get_details(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    PyInterpreterState *interp = PyInterpreterState_Get();
    void *obmalloc = interp->obmalloc; // Compilation Error: incomplete definition of type 'struct _is'

    ...
}

... // other stuff
```

Comment: Have you considered that the interpreter state is defined the way it is exactly to protect the parts you're talking about from being accessed other than by the interpreter itself?  What do you want the data for, anyway?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, I thought about that and agree with you. I'm trying to analyze Python's memory management without hacking the CPython source code. But if there is no other way to do it, then I guess I'll have to customize CPython a bit for the purpose.